# SFDX Scratch Orgs: User access to prod org

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org

We have an SQA org (Performance edition), and several dev environments (Performance edition too). I'm trying to set up a scratch org, but any of this orgs has "Dev hub" as an option to enable.
However, oficial documentation says the opposite: 
[Dev Hub available in: Developer, Enterprise, Performance, and Unlimited Editions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs.htm)

If this is true, and the only way to set as "Dev hub" is production org, does it mean it's need to provide production access to every developer who needs to create a new scratch org?

Thanks in advance, and sorry for the silly question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dev Hub is available in your production org or in Developer Edition orgs (with *much* lower limits). It is not available in sandboxes of any edition.

> does it mean it's need to provide production access to every developer who needs to create a new scratch org?

Yes, but you can configure them with [minimal permissions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_add_users.htm) to interact only with the SFDX objects. They don't need system administrator access or access to any data besides the special objects used by Dev Hub to track scratch orgs.

Comment: Thanks to take the time to respond.